# How do you return a pointer to an object in order to use in functions that access the objects methods?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've looked everywhere, and I cannot find a clear answer for my exact question here. Or perhaps I have found the answer, but I don't understand it completely.

I have 3 objects:

```
Foo Object1;
Foo Object2;
Foo Object3;
```

I have a function where a user chooses from a list of strings that correlate to objects. When the user inputs, say "B", I want to now perform operations on Object2.

Here is essentially what I have.

```
string getOption()
{
    string option;

    cout << "Option Menu" << endl;
    cout << "A - Option 1" << endl;    // Object1
    cout << "B - Option 2" << Lendl;   // Object2
    cout << "C - Option 3" << endl;    // Object3

    cin >> option;

    return option;
```

Now that I have the input, I want to perform numerous options on the object. Something like:

```
void modifyFooString(foo userSelectedObject)
{
    // Local variables
    string userInput;


    userInput = readInput(); // Function that reads valid input

    userSelectedObject.setMethod(userInput);
}
```

But with numerous functions. It's in a while loop, so I need to modify the object and then re-prompt the user if they want to make changes to a different object.

When I look at this problem, I think a pointer can be used. For example:

```
void getOption(Foo* &choice)
{
    string option;

    cout << "Option Menu" << endl;
    cout << "A - Option 1" << endl;    // Object1
    cout << "B - Option 2" << Lendl;   // Object2
    cout << "C - Option 3" << endl;    // Object3

    cin >> option;

    if (option == "A")
        choice = &Object1;

    else if (option == "A")
        choice = &Object2;

    if (option == "A")
        choice = &Object3;
}
```

So ideally, I can use the pointer now in the functions proceeding the `getOption()` function to modify the selected object. However, when I try to implement it like this, it's just not working.

How do I return a pointer that can be used to modify a selected object?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't edit the question to correct the obvious mistakes in the code. If the mistakes in the code are typos then let the OP fix them.

Comment: How isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have more success with

```
if (option == "A")
    choice = &Object1;
else if (option == "B")
    choice = &Object2;
else if (option == "C")
    choice = &Object3;
```

You should also clarify what 'it's just not working' actually means.

Since you want to **return** something, it more natural to use a C++ return statement.

```
Foo* getOption()
{
    ...
    if (option == "A")
        return &Object1;
    else if (option == "B")
        return &Object2;
    else if (option == "C")
        return &Object3;
```

Comment: With this being the case, would I do something like:
`Foo * fooPtr;
fooPtr = getOption();
`
in order to store the pointer in the `fooPtr` variable? Furthermore, once it's stored, can I use `fooPtr` in other functions in the same way I would use the object it's pointing to?

Comment: Yes for the first question but no for the second. Typical case is `foo.something()` for the object but `fooPtr->something()` for the object pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Same as john's answer, but with the if-else-ladder being replaced by something I think clearer :)

```
Foo* getOption() {
   ...
   return option == "A" ? &Object1 :
          option == "B" ? &Object2 :
          option == "C" ? &Object3 :
                          nullptr  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example for your problem,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
class Foo
{
public:
    int id;
    int data;
    Foo(int tid,int tdata)
    {
        id = tid;
        data = tdata;
    }
};

Foo *Object1 = new Foo(1,0);
Foo *Object2 = new Foo(2,0);
Foo *Object3 = new Foo(3,0);

Foo* getOption()
{
    char option;

    cout << "Option Menu" << endl;
    cout << "A - Option 1" << endl;    // Object1
    cout << "B - Option 2" << endl;   // Object2
    cout << "C - Option 3" << endl;    // Object3

    cin >> option;

    switch (option)
    {
    case 'A':
        return Object1;
        break;
    case 'B':
        return Object2;
        break;
    case 'C':
        return Object3;
        break;
    default:
        cout << option ;
        break;
    }
        return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << (getOption())->id;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

In this example you will answer

> 1 for option == A
>
> 2 for option == B
>
> 3 for option == C

The main changes I have done are,

```
1. changed

    if (option == "A") // comparing A
        choice = &Object1;

    else if (option == "A") // Comparing B
        choice = &Object2;

    if (option == "A") //comparing C
        choice = &Object3;

to 

  switch (option)
    {
    case 'A':
        return Object1;
        break;
    case 'B':
        return Object2;
        break;
    case 'C':
        return Object3;
        break;
    default:
        cout << option ;
        break;
    }

2. changed
 option == "A" to  option == 'A' format // when I have used if instead of switch
```

try this and let me know if it is helpful for you